# ArrayFormula IF ROW Not empty then iterate through formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to make an Array Formula to go down my Spreadsheet copying the formula but increasing the none fixed fields and removing the FALSE returns.

Here is what I currently have:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(I2,Data!$A$2:$E$17,5,0)*J2))
```

But as it goes down it's still returning the same number meaning that I2 and J2 haven't increased and I cannot seem to remove the "FALSE" When A2:A<>"" is empty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide `I2` and `J2` also as a range, otherwise, as the formula is only in one cell, the reference won't change even if it is dynamic.

The false issue can be fixed by putting `""` in the else clause.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A <> "", VLOOKUP(I2:I, Data!$A$2:$E$17, 5, 0) * J2:J, ""))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Took a while to work it out.  Thanks.

Comment: epic answer nice bro